# session time out

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, iis-7, c#-3.0

I use asp.net and set the session timeout using

```
Session.Timeout = 1440;
```

but the session timed out, is there anything shall I fix or adjust in iis 7 and 6

Best regards

Comment: Did you set the TimeOut value in your web.config? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Icarus I tried it but it failed

Answer (score 2):

This may work

```
<configuration>
  <sessionstate 
      mode="inproc"
      cookieless="false" 
      timeout="1440" 
  />
</configuration>
```

Comment: where did you use the timeout, it can be done in the web.config and page backend code as well

Comment: it give session timeout, even by using that

Answer (score 1):

If the sessionstate timeout in the web config is not working check for memory leaks in your application. I had the same problem in a legacy application I inherited. After a lot if digging I found some custom server controls with static variables and static objects referenced by multiple pages and other objects. This caused the application to never release resources. Eventually IIS recycles the pool when it runs out of memory. When the pool is recycled all sessions will be unloaded from memory also.